# Can strcpy affect strcmp results in c language?

Tags: c

Edit: Changed title to reflect both methods in post.

I'm trying to compare two strings in c language as below but for some reason it's always printing that both strings are not equal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    /* A nice long string */

    char test[30]="hellow world";

    char test2[30];

    // to copy string from first array to second array

    strcpy(test2, test);



    /* now comparing two stering*/

    if(strcmp(test2, test))
       printf("strigs are equal  ");
    else

    printf("not equal  \n");

    printf("value of first string  is %s and second string is %s",test,test2);
    printf("length of string1 is %zu and other string is %zu ",strlen(test2),strlen(test2));



}
```

I'm always getting output as

```
not equal  
value of first string  is hellow world and second string is hellow worldlength of string1 is 12 and other string is 12
```

Comment: Think of `strcmp()` as returning the difference (for peculiar values of "difference") between the strings. If the difference is `0`, the strings are equal.

Comment: Also, you can use `\n` in the printf format string to go to a new line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i understand the problem. In java if both strings were equal then if condition equates to true. I had assumed the same in C and made mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is with how you're using `strcmp`. `strcmp` returns 0 (which evaluates as false) when the strings are equal (and returns a positive number when the strings are "in order" and a negative number when they're "out of order").

Comment: AFAIK, you can't rely on ±1, only on positive/negative.

Answer (score 6):

[strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) returns 0 when two strings are the same, and 0 evaluates to false in C. Try:

```
if(strcmp(test2, test)==0)
```

Answer (score 4):

As per C++ reference
`Return value of strcmp
-A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
-A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a            greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.`

Alter your condition to `if(!strcmp(test2, test))` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

strcmp() returns 0 if the strings are equal. See, for example, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp()` returns 0 on equality

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` return 0 if the given two strings are equal.

I have also fixed few spelling mistakes and in the last `printf()` you have called `strlen(test2)` two times! - correct that as well

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    /* A nice long string */

    char test[30]="hello world";

    char test2[30];

    // to copy string from first array to second array

    strcpy(test2, test);

    /* now comparing two stering*/

    if(!strcmp(test2, test))
        printf("strigs are equal \n");
    else
        printf("not equal  \n");

    printf("value of first string is %s \nsecond string is %s \n", test, test2);
    printf("length of string1 is %zu \nsecond string is %zu \n",strlen(test), strlen(test2));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
strigs are equal 
value of first string is hello world 
second string is hello world 
length of string1 is 11 
second string is 11 
$
```

Answer (score 1):

man strcmp: "The  strcmp()  function  compares  the  two  strings s1 and s2.  It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2."